# How to verify highlighted text present in PDF using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to verify the highlighted text present in pdf content.I am using selenium webdriver for automation .Is there any way how can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: firstly, depend on language you write, you can use PDF libraries to read it. then, you can compare process. it is not directly related with selenium

Answer (score 1):

You can use an API called **PDFbox** to perform pdf related operation in Selenium.
[Here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi) is the link to download the required files.

Below is the sample approach you can use to search the content in PDF.

```
driver.get("URL where PDF can be found");
URL url = new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl());
BufferedInputStream fileToParse = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(fileToParse);
parser.parse();
```

Below line will print the content of PDF.

```
System.out.println(new PDFTextStripper().getText(parser.getPDDocument()));
```

Below line will store the contents in String variable.

```
String output = new PDFTextStripper().getText(parser.getPDDocument());
```

Once you get contents in String variable you can easily search it in below manner.

```
if(output.contains("Lieferantenkürzelabcd")){
    System.out.println("True");
}else{
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I guess this code helps in searching text in pdf content.But I am looking for  something just to verify whether the text is highlighted in pdf.Ex: to verify whether above text "Lieferantenkürzelabcd" is highlighted in pdf with background color yellow or anything similar to that using selenium webdriver.